# GWT problem, GWT.create(SomeClass.class) throw exception

Tags: java, gwt, binding, deferred

i have a gwt project and using method GWT.create(SomeClass.class) throw exception. 
The exception is :

```
Loading module: Webcharge
  Top URL: http://127.0.0.1:8888/Webcharge.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997
  User agent: Chrome
  Remote host: wsta1:39330
  Tab key: 
  Session key: v2aC'2^b3!lQgZS6
DEBUG: Validating newly compiled units. 
  ERROR: Errors in 'jar:file:/home/devel/Downloads/gwt-2.3.0/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/gwt/editor/client/EditorDriver.java'. 
    ERROR: Line 97: No source code is available for type javax.validation.ConstraintViolation<T>; did you forget to inherit a required module?. 
  ERROR: Errors in 'jar:file:/home/devel/Downloads/gwt-2.3.0/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/gwt/editor/client/impl/BaseEditorDriver.java'. 
    ERROR: Line 67: No source code is available for type javax.validation.ConstraintViolation<T>; did you forget to inherit a required module?. 
  ERROR: Errors in 'jar:file:/home/devel/Downloads/gwt-2.3.0/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/gwt/editor/client/impl/SimpleViolation.java'. 
    ERROR: Line 40: No source code is available for type javax.validation.ConstraintViolation<T>; did you forget to inherit a required module?. 
  ERROR: Errors in 'jar:file:/home/devel/Downloads/gwt-2.3.0/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/gwt/editor/client/testing/MockSimpleBeanEditorDriver.java'. 
    ERROR: Line 108: No source code is available for type javax.validation.ConstraintViolation<T>; did you forget to inherit a required module?. 
  ERROR: Errors in 'file:/home/devel/webcharge/webapp-gwt/src/gmgsys/com/webcharge/client/DataSource.java'. 
    ERROR: Line 15: No source code is available for type gmgsys.com.webcharge.model.MyUser; did you forget to inherit a required module?. 
  ERROR: Errors in 'file:/home/devel/webcharge/webapp-gwt/src/gmgsys/com/webcharge/client/MainPanel.java'. 
    ERROR: Line 124: No source code is available for type gmgsys.com.webcharge.model.MyUser; did you forget to inherit a required module?. 
  ERROR: Errors in 'file:/home/devel/webcharge/webapp-gwt/src/gmgsys/com/webcharge/client/MyTable.java'. 
  ERROR: Errors in 'file:/home/devel/webcharge/webapp-gwt/src/gmgsys/com/webcharge/client/WebchargeService.java'. 
  ERROR: Errors in 'file:/home/devel/webcharge/webapp-gwt/src/gmgsys/com/webcharge/client/WebchargeServiceAsync.java'. 
    ERROR: Line 46: No source code is available for type gmgsys.com.webcharge.model.MyUser; did you forget to inherit a required module?. 
    ERROR: Line 13: No source code is available for type gmgsys.com.webcharge.model.MyUser; did you forget to inherit a required module?. 
  ERROR: Errors in 'jar:file:/home/devel/Downloads/gwt-2.3.0/gwt-user.jar!/javax/validation/super/javax/validation/Configuration.java'. 
    ERROR: Line 12: No source code is available for type gmgsys.com.webcharge.model.MyUser; did you forget to inherit a required module?. 
  ERROR: Errors in 'jar:file:/home/devel/Downloads/gwt-2.3.0/gwt-user.jar!/javax/validation/ConstraintViolationException_CustomFieldSerializer.java'. 
  ERROR: Errors in 'jar:file:/home/devel/Downloads/gwt-2.3.0/gwt-user.jar!/javax/validation/super/javax/validation/MessageInterpolator.java'. 
    ERROR: Line 93: No source code is available for type javax.validation.TraversableResolver; did you forget to inherit a required module?. 
    ERROR: Line 105: No source code is available for type javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorFactory; did you forget to inherit a required module?. 
    ERROR: Line 202: No source code is available for type javax.validation.ValidatorFactory; did you forget to inherit a required module?. 
  ERROR: Errors in 'jar:file:/home/devel/Downloads/gwt-2.3.0/gwt-user.jar!/javax/validation/super/javax/validation/constraints/Pattern.java'. 
    ERROR: Line 30: No source code is available for type javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException; did you forget to inherit a required module?. 
    ERROR: Line 39: No source code is available for type javax.validation.ConstraintViolation<T>; did you forget to inherit a required module?. 
    ERROR: Line 66: No source code is available for type javax.validation.metadata.ConstraintDescriptor<T>; did you forget to inherit a required module?. 
    ERROR: Line 75: No source code is available for type javax.validation.Payload; did you forget to inherit a required module?. 
  ERROR: Errors in 'jar:file:/home/devel/Downloads/gwt-2.3.0/gwt-user.jar!/javax/validation/super/javax/validation/spi/ConfigurationState.java'. 
    ERROR: Line 93: No source code is available for type javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorFactory; did you forget to inherit a required module?. 
    ERROR: Line 107: No source code is available for type javax.validation.TraversableResolver; did you forget to inherit a required module?. 
DEBUG: Rebinding com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.SchedulerImpl. 
  DEBUG: Checking rule <generate-with class='com.google.gwt.editor.rebind.SimpleBeanEditorDriverGenerator'/>. 
    WARN: Detected warnings related to 'com.google.gwt.editor.client.SimpleBeanEditorDriver'.   Are validation-api-<version>.jar and validation-api-<version>-sources.jar on the classpath?. 
    INFO: Specify -logLevel DEBUG to see all errors.. 
    WARN: Unknown type 'com.google.gwt.editor.client.SimpleBeanEditorDriver' specified in deferred binding rule. 
DEBUG: Rebinding gmgsys.com.webcharge.client.WebchargeService. 
  DEBUG: Checking rule <generate-with class='com.google.gwt.user.rebind.ui.ImageBundleGenerator'/>. 
    ERROR: Unable to find type 'gmgsys.com.webcharge.client.WebchargeService'. 
      ERROR: Hint: Previous compiler errors may have made this type unavailable. 
      ERROR: Hint: Check the inheritance chain from your module; it may not be inheriting a required module or a module may not be adding its source path entries properly. 
ERROR: Deferred binding failed for 'gmgsys.com.webcharge.client.WebchargeService'; expect subsequent failures. 
ERROR: Unable to load module entry point class gmgsys.com.webcharge.client.Webcharge (see associated exception for details). java.lang.RuntimeException: Deferred binding failed for 'gmgsys.com.webcharge.client.WebchargeService' (did you forget to inherit a required module?)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.GWTBridgeImpl.create(GWTBridgeImpl.java:53)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.create(GWT.java:98)
    at gmgsys.com.webcharge.client.WebchargeService$App.<clinit>(WebchargeService.java:20)
    at gmgsys.com.webcharge.client.MainPanel.<init>(MainPanel.java:22)
    at gmgsys.com.webcharge.client.Webcharge.onModuleLoad(Webcharge.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:396)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:193)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:510)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:352)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.rebind(ModuleSpace.java:595)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.rebindAndCreate(ModuleSpace.java:455)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.GWTBridgeImpl.create(GWTBridgeImpl.java:49)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.create(GWT.java:98)
    at gmgsys.com.webcharge.client.WebchargeService$App.<clinit>(WebchargeService.java:20)
    at gmgsys.com.webcharge.client.MainPanel.<init>(MainPanel.java:22)
    at gmgsys.com.webcharge.client.Webcharge.onModuleLoad(Webcharge.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:396)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:193)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:510)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:352)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
ERROR: Failed to load module 'Webcharge' from user agent 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/534.24 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/11.0.696.57 Safari/534.24' at wsta1:39330.
```

and a few explanation

Webcharge is my entry point for the project, as you can see in the stacktrace the exception is thrown **(WebchargeService.java:21)** where at that line i have 
  **private static WebchargeServiceAsync ourInstance = GWT.create(WebchargeService.class);**

WebchargeService

```
@RemoteServiceRelativePath(value = "WebchargeService")
public interface WebchargeService extends RemoteService
{
String getMessage(MyUser user);
List<MyUser> getUserList();
List<MyUser> updateUser(MyUser user) throws Exception;
List<MyUser> selectByName(String name);
String getMessage(String msg);

public static class App
{
  private static WebchargeServiceAsync ourInstance = GWT.create(WebchargeService.class);

  public static synchronized WebchargeServiceAsync getInstance()
  {
    return ourInstance;
  }
}
}
```

and the code for WebchargeServiceAsync

```
public interface WebchargeServiceAsync
{
void getMessage(String msg, AsyncCallback<String> async);

void getMessage(MyUser user, AsyncCallback<String> async);

void getUserList(AsyncCallback<List<MyUser>> async);

void updateUser(MyUser user, AsyncCallback<List<MyUser>> async);

void selectByName(String name, AsyncCallback<List<MyUser>> async);
}
```

Any help is welcome :)

Thanks.

Comment: Don't you have some other output telling you what the error with WebchartServiceAsync is?

Comment: Yes, it's likely that you can see another error in your hosted mode console, that is probably causing this.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I just have updated the exception, now that's all output i got.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GWT 2.3 requires javax.validation jar: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api/1.0.0.GA

Download it and add it to your project lib folder.

Comment: I got the same exception even when i import a existing sample project. For example i tried this one - hg clone https://gwt-dispatch-example.googlecode.com/hg/ gwt-dispatch-example
but again exception is thrown executing  private final MyGinjector injector = GWT.create(MyGinjector.class);

Comment: Just something is generally wrong with my env. Please if you have any suggestions let me know, i m desperate :-)

Comment: Try using this sample project with GWT version before 2.2.

Comment: You need gin-1.5-post-gwt-2.2.jar with GWT 2.2 and 2.3

Comment: This example project uses Gin 1.0. It won't work under GWT 2.2 or 2.3.

Answer (score 14):

today I had exactly the same problem. here is the solution:

the files: validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources.jar and validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar which can be found in the downloadable gwt sdk should be in your classpath when compiling or executing dev-mode. the sources jar is critical, therefore Peter's solution did not work.

Comment: does it have to be this exact version though?

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem which was caused by *typo*

**Wrong (throws Cast Exception):**

```
private final UserService userRpcService = GWT.create(UserService.class);
```

**Correct (added ...Async):**

```
private final UserServiceAsync userRpcService = GWT.create(UserService.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

as the exception already stated: *did you forget to inherit a required module?*

For example, is the "MyUser" available?

Comment: What do you mean under "available" ? yes i have a bean class MyUser. But i don't understand this message - >  did you forget to inherit a required module?

Comment: _did you forget to inherit a required module_ phrase is always related to your gwt.xml file, asking if you have forgotten to _<inherits>_ any library, jar or external module. In other cases, when you use some unsupported java classes on client side, you will get this error too.

Answer (score 1):

After reading this question and looking at the answers, here's the solution:

**If you updated your libraries manually by copying the new gwt files :** (which a lot of us did)

1. copy your validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar and validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources.jar into the gwt-dependencies directory.
2. remove all VAADIN_DOWNLOAD variables from your classpath.
3. Add the following variables to the project's build path with the following entries:
   gwt-dev.jar, gwt-user.jar,validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar AND validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources.jar.
4. Compile widgetset
5. Enjoy life

**If you haven't updated your libraries manually by copying the new gwt files :**

1. Update your plug-in
2. Make sure the files validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar AND validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources.jar are present in the gwt-dependencies directory
3. Modify the existing variables and add the 2 new variable entries (validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar AND validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources.jar) into your classpath.
4. Compile widgetset
5. Enjoy life